# transform is not being called when parsing a file

Tags: papaparse

I am using papaparse and I would like to transform my values as they are being parsed. I have added a transform function but it never gets called.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Papa.parse(file, {
    complete: ({data, errors, meta}) => {
        alert('I get called')
    },
    transform : (val, col)=>{
        alert('i dont get called')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated from **4.4** to **4.6** and now it works.